# How to politely tell a colleague they won't be an author of my article?

Tags: authorship

Looking for advice.

My coworkers and I have been working on a project for about two years, and we are right now in the process of writing a paper. About a year ago, we contacted a friend of mine who is also a researcher, told him about our results and asked for his insight. After a couple of zoom calls, he pointed us toward a research direction we had not thought about. After pursuing this direction for some time we found out it did not work, so we ended up doing something different which does not include our colleague’s suggestions at all.

Now, after discussing with the coauthors we have concluded that it is not fair for any of us to include this person as an author, since his contribution has been of no impact for the paper in the end. I agree with this decision. I also believe it would not be nice for our colleague to just find the paper online without any news, and especially since he is my/our friend I feel that I should send him the manuscript via email before sending it for publication. I wonder how I should I deal with the issue of authorship in this email: should I just send him the paper without him as an author? if so, should I explain to him that we do not think his contribution deserves it? or should I ask if he wants to be one? I am not familiar with the authorship etiquette…

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: Did you have an agreement regarding authorship when he provided the suggestions? Especially if he is your friend, you should first talk to him. Basically, tell him what you wrote here, but do it by phone, video call or in person.

Comment: You used that person for free consultation. You should ask them what is the price for time spend.

Comment: If you are SURE that his contribution was not part of your paper, you can thank him in the Acknowledgment section of your paper, giving his professional association details as well.

Comment: His contribution was useful as it caused you to evaluate and drop your initial direction leading you to where you are now. I helped a colleague with a small part and was included in the acknowledgement.

Comment: The borderline for what constitutes authorship varies a bit by subject. What in some areas would be authorship in others earns an acknowledgement. A good place to start would be thinking about how likely they would be to be expecting to be an author.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/155973/can-revision-authors-be-dropped-from-a-paper

Comment: Why do you think the friend expects to be a coauthor?

Comment: @SSimon: And who (and why) would pay this?

Comment: @user111388 OP who asked this

Comment: @Ssimon: Are you a researcher? Is it in your instition common practise that researchers pay out of their own pocket or charge money from other researchers (who presumably answer them while being paid for doing research)?

Comment: @Roland, I had no agreement, in our field it is common practice to share ideas like that. Maybe I should have talked about this in the beginning.

Comment: @Ssimon Nobody will pay for the publication, but if some expense comes up we will pay for it.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! I think he will not want to be an author anyway, but since he is my friend and this is my first time having all the responsability for a project, I was in doubt

Comment: A personal anecdote which may or may not be useful to OP: I'm listed as a co-author on a paper from 2003 where I was the creator of a very substantial section in some of the pre-submission drafts, but my contribution was completely cut from the final version due to the ultra-tight length limit of the journal to which the manuscript was submitted.  I'm very happy that my colleagues chose to keep me on the author list, but I wouldn't have felt that I had any right to demand it.

Comment: Why not consider the difference between "authors" and "contributors"?

Comment: Would you please mind sharing which field and country are you in? I find it a rather odd culture fellow researchers (and friends, while at it) expecting co-authorship just due to some insights. I've spent nights doing fully-fledged translations and reviews to help friends meet strict deadlines and all I've ever expected was them eventually returning the favour.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**TLDR:** Unless explicitly discussed otherwise, your friend does not expect to be a co-author. Just write a friendly email thanking them for the discussions and asking them if it is ok to include them in the acknowledgements.

As pointed out in the comments, this highly depends on which field we're talking about. In some fields, even pointing in a direction **that actually turned out to be right** might only be worth an acknowledgement (probably specific though, "we thank X for point to the results published in <obscure jounal 60 years ago>"). Since this is clear to most people, based on the information you provided, I would not think that your friend even expects to be co-author at all (unless they explicitly asked to be co-author, which would be border-line in terms of academic integrity but happens when the person urgently needs another co-authorship for formal reasons - in that case, however, one would expect that person to (a) communicate this clearly beforehand and (b) do much of the mindless busy-work, e.g. beautification of images).

That being said, I would assume that your friend knows they're not going to be co-author and thank them by email for the interesting, albeit ultimately fruitless discussions (but hey, maybe we can explore this in the future,...) and ask them if they agree to be mentioned in the acknowledgements. In other words, put a positive spin on it.

Comment: This. I would refuse accept authorship if I were the friend in this situation, and would probably find even an acknowledgement to be generous.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense. We will definitely add him in the acknowledgments and since I know him, I also think he probably will not want to be an author anyway.

Comment: @photonQ glad to hear that, these situations can be very awkward. If you think that this answers your question, feel free to "accept" it - with the checkmark (so it will be marked as "correct" for others in a similar situation).

Comment: @user129707thanks for the tip about accepting it, I am quite new in stackexchange :)

Comment: _asking them if it is ok to include them in the acknowledgements_ - I think this is a bit weird, though perhaps this varies by field or something?  I've never asked or been asked about such a thing.  I wouldn't even explicitly tell them I included an acknowledgement of them, but I might send a preprint and say thanks for their help.

Comment: I think that out of politeness, it is indeed a good practice to ask for the permission or notify the friend before writing their name in a paper, if it's not a citation. At least to be sure that their affiliation is correct for instance.

Comment: @photonQ Relating to that, don't forget that negative results *are* still results.  If it looked like a promising avenue but turned out not to be, make sure to document what it was and why, otherwise someone else will fall into that trap too.  And at that point it's natural to acknowledge your friend's contribution in making that suggestion, even if it didn't lead further.

Comment: @Kimball: From my experience (in pure maths/theoretical CS), asking people about acknowledging them isn’t required, but it’s common.  Firstly, it seems polite to inform people they’re going to be mentioned; and secondly, it feels more polite to phrase that as a question, than as just a statement.  (This may be a linguistic/cultural difference: phrasing a statement as a question, for politeness, is I think almost obligatory for most Brits, but is not so universal among Americans.)

Comment: If someone pointed me to a direction that turned out to be *right*, I might seriously consider offering them coauthorship or inviting them to work further on the topic. But that is not the case here. The suggested direction was *not fruitful* for the authors. But I otherwise agree with your thesis that the person probably does not expect to be coauthor.

Comment: @anemone Yes, but discovering that the proposed direction was not fruitful for the authors _was_ fruitful for the authors.

Comment: @JeffE Well that is something that is not so clear from the way the question is phrased: "we found out it did not work" can mean that the authors can demonstrate that the approach is fruitless (which is how many people have read it, i.e., as a kind of negative result) or it can mean that it just did not work for them. I was actually wondering, when reading the post, whether anything would have been at all different had the OP not asked his friend for help in the first place.

Comment: @anemone The mere fact that the situation is unclear argues against the stance that the friend _obviously_ should _not_ be a coauthor.  Negative results are still results; not all contributions appear in the text of the paper.  I agree that the friend probably doesn't _expect_ to be a coauthor, but I don't think the idea should be dismissed out of hand based on the extremely limited information we have.

Comment: @JeffE I am a stranger to the stance you quote. As a matter of fact I am not propositng anything, given I do not have enough facts. What I meant by "unclear" is "unclear to us from the given description of it". I assume there is a way for the OP to figure out whether the help of the friend had any other impact on the paper than the team spending time on the friend's proposal. In fact the OP presents us with a bit of an oxymoron, "the contribution was of no impact for the paper in the end". I commented on this answer highlighing the counterfactual case that a help would prove fruitful.

Answer (score 14):

*We made good progress pursuing direction X, but, it didn't work out due to Y, so we pursued Z, as described in the attached. We've included an acknowledgement of your input. Thanks again.*

Answer (score 7):

Under the circumstances, I doubt your friend expects co-authorship of the paper.  Your idea of sending a courtesy email to let him know of your proposed decision (instead of having him read the paper and see he is not on it) sounds like a good idea to me.  I recommend you write a courteous email thanking him for his help, letting him know that you and your colleagues discussed the issue, and letting him know your thinking on the matter.  Do not frame this as a decision that has already been made --- instead, offer him an opportunity to respond before you and your colleagues make your final decision, in case he disgrees with your views and wishes to make an argument for his inclusion.  Do not invite co-authorship unless you intend to follow through on that.

It is also worth noting that you could give your friend an *acknowledgement* in the paper rather than co-authorship.  If you decide that this is appropriate then you could offer this as an alternative to co-authorship.  If your description of events is accurate, the most likely response is that your friend will be happy to have had a chance to hear about the matter before seeing the published paper, and most likely he will agree that he has not done enough to warrant co-authorship.  In the unlikely event that your friend insists that he deserves co-authorship, refer the matter for decision to your Head of Department or some other third-party for an independent decision.

Answer (score 5):

Often the process of discovery can take you down roads which lead to nowhere. It's sometimes useful to point that out, in case others question what was tried in reaching your ultimate destination. Though authorship may not be appropriate, and effort was expended and some kind of recognition for effort and contribution may be appropriate, it can often help others to understand more deeply when you leave signs along the way, "don't go this way, because of this."

Just a thought.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid I have to disagree with many of the above answers. It does not matter whether the approach your friend suggested panned out or not. It matters how much *work* your friend did. If it took him 3 years of experiments to invalidate a promising approach, then yes, the contribution was valuable and he deserves a co-authorship even if the approach did not solve the problem. Of course, in the other extreme, a few minutes chat and a suggestion to try running the data through a different filter, may not merit authorship even if it has cracked the case.

Your colleague devoted time an resources to your problem. Consider the next time you consult him. Do you still expect him to devote the same amount of effort? Why?

Specifically in your case, a few zoom calls may not be considered a lot of effort, but the reason for not adding him as an author should not be "it didn't help", but rather "I didn't waste his time".